# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on js

Tags: javascript, html

This is my javascript code.

```
var customerNodea = document.getElementsByName("cartquantity");      
for(var i = 0; i < customerNodea.length; i++){   
    var customer = document.getElementById("quantity"+i);
    customer.addEventListener("change", func, false);   
}
```

on my html
i have

```
id="quantity1"
id="quantity2"
id="quantity3"
```

. .etc

Any help will be appreciated , thanks!

Comment: The first time through your loop you are trying to access ‘quantity0’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your `for` loop you are starting the counter at `0`. So the first time through your loop your code asks for:

```
var customer = document.getElementById("quantity0");
```

Which is null, hence your error.

You can change your loop to start at `1` and finish at `3` with:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= customerNodea.length; i++) {   
    var customer = document.getElementById("quantity"+i);
    customer.addEventListener("change", func, false);   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var customerNodea = document.getElementsByName("cartquantity");      
for(var i = 0; i < customerNodea.length; i++) {   
    var customer = document.getElementById("quantity"+parseInt(i+1));
    customer.addEventListener("change", func, false);   
}
```

Comment: Whereas your answer is correct, it contains only code (mostly copied from the answer). It would be better to just point that `i` goes with `0,1,2` values whereas elements' `id`s contains `1,2,3`.